# CSS table td color

Tags: html, css

Am using this in Wordpress Tablepress plugin.

I have these codes to highlight the table rows. Is there anyway I can merge them into single row to reduce the repeated codes?

```css
.tablepress-id-1 .row-2 td {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.tablepress-id-1 .row-13 td {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.tablepress-id-1 .row-15 td {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.tablepress-id-1 .row-19 td {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.tablepress-id-1 .row-23 td {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.tablepress-id-1 .row-26 td {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.tablepress-id-1 .row-35 td {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.tablepress-id-1 .row-35 td {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Do the numbers have any significance or sequence?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: And if there is no sequence this is just basic CSS to do `.tablepress-id-1 .row-2 td, .tablepress-id-1 .row-13 td ... { .... }`

Comment: You tagged this post with html tag. Where's the html then?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can separate multiple CSS selectors with commas:

```css
.tablepress-id-1 .row-2 td,
.tablepress-id-1 .row-13 td,
.tablepress-id-1 .row-15 td
{
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: thanks. this worked well.

Answer (score 3):

Just apply an identical class to the elements you want to style. And insert it into your css file.

```
.identicalClass {
 background-color: #000000;
 color: #ffffff;
}
```